# Differences between getRange, getDataRange, and getActiveRange?

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

If it isn't immediately apparent by the question, I am pretty new to Google Apps Script. I'm trying to write a Spreadsheets function that runs through each row of a form submission sheet in a workbook and update a second sheet/range (in the same workbook) based on the values of the cells in the first using a for loop. However, nothing happens when I run the function.

I'm pretty sure the error is in how I'm defining the ranges in question, but I'm not 100% sure. Here's a modified version of what I've written:

```
function update() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var secondSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var submissionSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var secondRowEnd = secondSheet.getLastRow();
  var submissionRowEnd = submissionSheet.getLastRow();

  var secondColumnEnd = secondSheet.getLastColumn();
  var submissionColumnEnd = submissionSheet.getLastColumn(); //used to define ranges dynamically

  var secondRange = secondSheet.getValues();
  var submissionRange = submissionSheet.getValues();

  for(var i = 2; i <= submissionRowEnd; i++) {

    var rock = secondRange.getCell(i, 1).getValue();
    var paper = secondRange.getCell(i, 2).getValue();
    var scissors = secondRange.getCell(i, 3).getValue();

    var status = secondRange.getCell(i, 4).getValue();
    var forStatus = secondRange.getCell(i, 5).getValue();

    if (status === "Do X!") {
      for(var j = 2; j <= submissionRowEnd; j++) {

        var jrock = submissionRange.getCell(j, 1).getValue();
        var jpaper = submissionRange.getCell(j, 2).getValue();
        var jscissors = submissionRange.getCell(j, 3).getValue();
        var jstatus = submissionRange.getCell(j, 4).getValue();

        if (status === forStatus) {
          jrock.setValue(rock);
          jpaper.setValue(paper);
          jscissors.setValue(scissors);
        } else { /*do nothing*/ }
      }
    }
  }
```

I've been staring at slightly different versions of this code for weeks now, so any and all eyes on this would be greatly, greatly appreciated!

Comment: Javascript != Java and from your code it seems you're using Javascript, so please remove the Java tag.

Comment: Answered my own question: isolating individual cells by using getRange() instead of getCell().getValue() seems to have done the trick. I'm too inexperienced to know whether or not that's a "pretty" solution, but it works!

Answer (score 10):

Just checkout out the Apps Script API reference for the [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/). All the functions are documented there. Here are links to descriptions of the methods you need:

- [Spreadsheet.getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getactiverange)
- [Sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)

**getRange()** has multiple implementations.

- [Sheet.getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column)
- [Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows)
- [Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns)
- [Sheet.getRange(a1notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)

Answer (score 5):

the usage of `Sheet.getDataRange()` yields to a fast response time compared to `Sheet.getRange()`, since `Sheet.getDataRange()` returns a data array

Hope This Helps (HTH)

Answer (score 1):

Your spreadsheet in gdrive communicates with your function in the google apps script for every `getRange().getValue()`.
That is, the number of cells that are data, maybe a hundred times or more.

```
function update() {var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var secondSheet=ss.getSheets()[1];var submissionSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var secondRowEnd=secondSheet.getLastRow();
var data = submissionSheet.getDataRange();//here is all 
datasecondSheet.getRange(secondRowEnd).setValue(data.map(function (x){return 
x=data.filter( function (){blabla})}))}
```